# A duplicate Webview

Tags: android, webview

Here is my problem :

I want to display exactly the same website twice on the screen. My first approch was to have two `Webviews` and load the website in each of them. The problem is very poor performance (websites I'm loading are quite complex).

My second approach was to load the website in one of the `WebView` and duplicate it to the second. I failed in this approach.

My last try is to extend the `Webview` for giving it two `Canvas`. But I have absolutely no idea of how to do this. This is why I'm here ^^

More specifications of my problem :

**The layout :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.josselin.panoviewer.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you see, very simple : each view take exactly the half of the screen.
There will be no interaction between the website and the user.

My goal is to make an app that will allow users to see website using gyroscope and accelerometer with the Durovis Dive.

If you have a better approach, I'm all ear open !

Edit 1 :
Here is my BitmapWebview which take two ImageView in parameters. I draw in the ImageView Bitmap canvas and not in the Webview one :

```
public class BitmapWebView extends WebView {

private ImageView left, right;
private Bitmap bm;
private Canvas cn;

public BitmapWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setImagesViews(ImageView left, ImageView right){
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

private int width, height;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int ow, int oh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, ow, oh);
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.width, this.height, Config.ARGB_8888);
    cn = new Canvas(bm);
    this.left.setImageBitmap(bm);
    this.right.setImageBitmap(bm);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(cn);
}

}
```

My problem now is that some images in the website are loaded in ajax and so are not displayed in the ImageView...

Edit 2 : [SOLUTION]

It works ! Here the solution : instead of drawing canvas of imageView from the webview, I used the draw function of the WebView in a extended ImageView :

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

private WebView webview;

public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setWebView(WebView webview){
    this.webview = webview;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    this.webview.draw(canvas);
    this.invalidate();
}

}
```

Thanks all for your help !

Comment: Instead of adding another webview on the right, you can take another instace from left one and add it to the right programaticaly , so it would be identical ;-)

Comment: I tried this solution but I have an error about the fact that a view can have only one parent, even if I put this other instance in the same layout...

Comment: Did you try loadedWebView.saveState(bundle); freshWebView.loadState(bundle); and then add them both to screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can capture an image of the original web page and show this image wherever you want. However in this way you cannot touch the URL links or HTML input/button on the duplicated page, since it's just a screenshot of the original one.

To be more specific, you can:

1. use `WebViewClassic.saveViewState()` and `loadViewState()` to save and show a copy of the web page.

or:

1. use `WebView.capturePicture()` which will result in a **android.graphics.Picture** object.

Or you can also refer to Android Open Source Browser: Tab.capture() to see how to create a snapshot of the WebView.

!!! Please note that such methods may not be consistent on different API levels.

Comment: This solution work ! But... It seems that image loaded from ajax are not displayed after in the onDraw method... The result is that everything appears but not the images... I edit my first post with detailed code

Answer (score 0):

If the poor performance is due to requesting the webservice you might use a HttpClient to query the webcontent and use WebView. loadDataWithBaseURL () to put this content in both webviews.